# Expectation formula proof

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X$ have a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Prove that $E(X-\mu)^2$=$\sigma^2$

Comment: Hard to know what to do! The usual **definition** of the variance, for general random variable $X$ with mean $\mu$, is E(X-\mu)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variance is defined by
$$
\operatorname{Var}X=\operatorname E[X-\operatorname EX]^2.
$$
$\operatorname EX=\mu$ for the normal distribution so you have that $\operatorname E[X-\mu]^2=\sigma^2$.

Comment: I thought variance of $X$ was $E[X^2]-E[X]^2$? What happens to the cross term, in this case $-2\mu^2$? Thanks

Comment: @user137090 We have that $\operatorname E[X-\operatorname EX]^2=\operatorname E[X^2-2X\operatorname EX+(\operatorname EX)^2]=\operatorname EX^2-2(\operatorname EX)^2+(\operatorname EX)^2=\operatorname EX^2-(\operatorname EX)^2$. Hence, $\operatorname{Var}X=\operatorname EX^2-(\operatorname EX)^2$.